# Loopback: How to stop a console command?

Tags: loopbackjs

I am running a loopback command through the command line.

the script is as follows:

```
const app = require('../../server/server');

let acquireToken = function() {
    app.stop();
};

acquireToken();
```

However this does not seem to work as stop() is not a function. So I have added this in the server.js file:

```
'use strict';

let loopback = require('loopback');
let boot = require('loopback-boot');
let app = module.exports = loopback();

let winston = require('./winston');

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    let baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    winston.info('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      let explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      winston.info('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

let server;
app.stop = () => {
  server.close();
}

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    server = app.start();
});

module.exports = app;
```

But require.main == module is preventing this from working as this gives me the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
```

What is the recommended way of making this work?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit misleading because you're trying to stop an express object returned from a `require` call, so a more accurate question is

> How do I start and stop a listening loopback app from another script?

In `server.js` change `app.start = function()` to `app.start = function(cb)` and add `if (cb) {cb()};` to the end.

```
'use strict';

let loopback = require('loopback');
let boot = require('loopback-boot');
let app = module.exports = loopback();

let winston = require('./winston');

app.start = function(cb) {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    let baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    winston.info('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      let explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      winston.info('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
    if (cb) cb();
  });
};

let server;
app.stop = () => {
  server.close();
}

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    server = app.start();
});

module.exports = app;
```

And for your file which starts and stops loopback

```
// Setup loopback, but don't start the server
const app = require('./server');

// Define our callback function
let acquireToken = function() {   
    app.server.close();  
    console.log('closed'); 
};

// Hold onto the listener object so we can stop it later and start the server with the callback which executes after startup.
app.server = app.start(acquireToken);
```

Comment: this actually just starts the webserver. it doesn't run the script.

Comment: Oh, my mistake I put the callback parameter there myself, I thought it was a loopback default.  I've put instructions on how to execute a function after a loopback server starts.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to do anything. The script is still running. Even though there is no error it is still active. I tried app.close() as well but no luck there either. I also tried to disconnect the database connection but nothing...

Comment: What do you mean still running?  The only two parts of loopback I know which are consistently connected to something are database connections and the http server.  Why exactly do you want to stop the server?

Comment: Since its a command running through cronjob I would like to stop the script after its done. I only get this to work through process.exit(); but that is not preferred as some of the processes (like writing logs, saving to db) may not have been completed.

Comment: Stopping the http server will stop all requests not originating from your javascript, so after waiting a few seconds or so (or a more sophisticated solution) you can be sure that your program is not doing something  if you are not initiating it.  You can then call process.exit().

Comment: ok thanks. I guess that will be the solution for now. Though somewhere this doesn't feel as an elegant solution.